# Child GameObject use world position but must use parent position in Canvas

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I create 2D game and I need Instantiate GameObjects (lines) in child, but when I set position to *0,0,0* in Instantiate my objects Instantiates in the center of scene but their position is *759, -150, -9720.*

---

[image]

By arrows I show place where I want to Instantiate lines

---

My Instantiate code

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpectrumPartManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public SpectrumPartObject spectrumPartObject;

    public void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < spectrumPartObject.linePositions.Length; i++)
        {
            Instantiate(spectrumPartObject.linePrefab, spectrumPartObject.linePositions[i], Quaternion.identity,
                transform);
        }
    }
}
```

---

*ScriptableObject* where I get position

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "Spectrum", menuName = "Spectrum")]
public class SpectumSettings : ScriptableObject
{
    public float spectrumLineWidth;
    public Vector3[] linePositions;
    public GameObject linePrefab;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be Instantiating SpriteRenderer objects inside of canvas. If you do it outside, your issue probably will be gone. If not, check Quentin's answer. If you want something to be part of UI, use image instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [`Transform.TransformPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformPoint.html). It takes 3 `float` (or `int`) as arguments.

Using it for your code:

```cs
float lpX = spectrumPartObject.linePositions[i].x;
float lpY = spectrumPartObject.linePositions[i].y;
float lpZ = spectrumPartObject.linePositions[i].z;

Vector3 modifiedPos = transform.TransformPoint(lpX, lpY, lpZ);

Instantiate(spectrumPartObject.linePrefab, modifiedPos, Quaternion.identity, transform);
```